# Rewrite Get Parameter in URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have an url like: `/?page=2/` and want to rewrite it to : `/page/2/`.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Language/hosting environment would really help here.

As ChvyVale mention if you are using php then using [mod_rewrite](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls) is your best bet.

If you are using .NET then you need to look into [ASP.NET Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Yes, I am using apache, but I can not find an example for my case.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/page/([0-9]{4})$ /?page=$1 [L]

I'm not sure if that would work for you or not.  I'm not very versed in using apache.